# Subdomains are the nameservers of the domain itself

Tags: dns, domain-registration, vps, nameserver

As I have had some research, it is a bit hard for domain distributors to set the nameservers to subdomains of the same domain, for example:

- **Domain:** example.com
- **Nameserver 1:** ns1.example.com
- **Nameserver 2:** ns2.example.com

What we are actually do, is the host a VPS for a domain, and we want to use its subdomains (that they are also linked to two separate public IPs) as nameservers.

However it has taken already a month, and we are still having problems. Could anyone suggests:

- Why technically it is so different than of using another domain for nameservers (as in that case it would take around 12 hours)
- Do you suggest to use another domain? If yes please share the technical reasons too.
- What if I use IPs for the nameservers directly?

Comment: I am not so sure I understand this. It is not a good idea to host your own DNS unless you really really really know what you are doing. There is no issue with using the registrars DNS. As well you are opening up a potential problem where if something goes wrong with the domain name, the name servers are not available to fix the problem. This is a huge point of failure if it should ever arise. I used to be a web host and while I did run my own DNS servers, two were sub-domains of my domain name and two were not. This assured fail-over for when things went wrong.

Comment: @closetnoc Actually I own the hardware of servers too, i.e. it is a small data center, so I am trying to build everything on my own. I have WHM/cPanel to configure the all the servers (including the DNS). So what I am thinking I add 2 more nameservers that are not from the same domain. Also I added one more point in the question, please consider that too.

Comment: I used to have 86 servers. ;-) It is fun to play! I still run my own stuff. DNS and FTP are the two most dangerous services in regard to security short of PHP applications on the web. Just know what you are doing. Research, research, research. Intrusion detection too. Also, keep in mind that if you have a problem with the parent domain name, there is no recovery if your SOAs are sub-domains of the parent. Your domain name should NOT be in your own DNS except as back-up or secondaries. Use the sub-domains as SOAs for your clients so that you can control things more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank **closetnoc** for the comments, and I got my answer from them, so I mention the summery here again as the answer:

- It is **never** a good practice to serve a domain with its own subdomains as its nameservers, as if the domain itself has a failure, there is no recovery for the same.
- The only time you can use the mentioned situation is when you use them as a backup of other nameservers.
- For using IPs as nameservers, the only drawback is that they are hard to remember and are so static, if IP fails, you need to reconfigure all the domains for your hosting with new nameservers.

Comment: The rules have changed since I used to do this- back in the day the ns?.example.com being used as SOAs for domains could not be CNAMEs but IP addresses and must exist on two separate networks in case of failure. My DNS servers were served by two networks and were available on two other networks.